# How can I set the limit on a Fluent Query?

Tags: swift, fluent, vapor

How can I set a limit and an offset on a Query using Vapor's `Fluent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to `import Fluent`

Then you'll get some compiler help to do the following:

```
var query = try <##YourModelClass##>.query()
query.limit = Limit(count: count, offset: offset)
```

Comment: Edit your question, rather than making comment!

Comment: Does the answer make sense? You replied after 1 minute you asked the question. I think editing the first post should be enough

Comment: I'm just trying to get the word out as it took a sec for me to figure this out and there are likely a few people to do the same.

Comment: @KKendall refer to `Luca's` comment

Comment: Yes! In that you can specify the answer! Because making a comment after 1 min doesn't make any sense

Comment: I still don't get it. Why not add an answer in the answer section?

Comment: This is built into SO, there's a `Answer your own question` check mark below the question input.